# How do I embed a video from youtube into a jade file?

Tags: pug

How do I embed a video from youtube into a jade file?

I found how to embed an image and i tried doing something similar by doing

```
video(width='320', height='240', controls='controls')
        source(src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/Iy3xURDGZd0?list=PLkzo92owKnVwnV5o1psI7XSA-AquO9_9g', type='video/mp4', id='theVideo')
```

but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<video>` tag requires a **direct** link to the video stream (.mp4/.ogv), something which for a Youtube video you can't easily get, or legally even use on your site.

Youtube only allows its videos to be embedded on other web pages through certain ways as describe here: https://developers.google.com/youtube

Basically either using an iframe:

```
iframe(type='text/html' width='640' height='390'
    src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com'
    frameborder='0')
```

or through its Javascript API.